# Testing POST request to Posts controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to test the outcome of a direct POST request issued by an unauthorized user to the Posts controller of my Rails 4 blog app. Following Rails Tutorial, I have already implemented a functional test for the Users controller as follows:

```
describe 'attempting to issue a direct POST request while not signed in' do
    before { post users_path }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to signin_path }
end
```

However, attempting to do the same test on the Posts controller fails in the `before` block:

```
describe 'attempting to issue a direct POST request while not signed in' do
    before { post posts_path }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to signin_path }
end

ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Equivalent tests containing `patch post_path(post)` and `delete post_path(post)` function and pass thanks to a before_action in the controller.

My routes:

```
       posts GET    /posts(.:format)                       posts#index
             POST   /posts(.:format)                       posts#create
    new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                   posts#new
   edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)              posts#edit
        post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#show
             PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#update
             PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#update
             DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#destroy
```

Is RSpec getting confused by POST/Post(s) - i.e. the name of the request vs. the name of the controller?

Comment: It's probably confused because posting to create expects parameters.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I understand the point, but the exact same test works with the Users controller, and in the Rails Tutorial with the Microposts controller (listing 10.23). Both the User and the Posts models (and Hartl's Microposts) validate the presence of several parameters so, if the problem was as you suggest, sending an empty POST request should not work for any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was indeed a confusion between the method and model names, though I wasn't looking far enough upstream to see it: my tests were set up as follows:

```
describe 'in the Posts controller' do
  let(:post) { Post.create(...) }
  .
  .
  .
  describe 'attempting to issue a direct POST request while not signed in' do
    before { post posts_path } # 'post' is interpreted to be the variable!
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to signin_path }
  end
end
```

So, there was a naming conflict between the HTTP method POST and the *variable* 'post' declared at the beginning of the test block. Renaming the variable to 'test_post' fixed everything.

D'oh!

@DaveNewton: evidently, in cases where the POST request is rejected outright, it is possible to test it without parameters.

Comment: Dude, thank you! I've been racking my brain on this for hours.